# Ubuntu 14.04 Razer megladon headset is not found

Tags: drivers, sound

I have just installed Ubuntu on my ASUS laptop running 14.04.

Now, I tried to connect my USB [razer megaladon](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-audio/razer-megalodon) and it seems like its turned on (it lights up).

However, I am unable to find the device in my sound settings:

[image]

Or in the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:57b4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 13d3:3414 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am guessing its because its missing a driver that it usually would install by it self, however I'm not quite sure how to do this on Ubuntu.

So, how can I get this device to work on Ubuntu?

Comment: Did it come with a driver CD or a website to download drivers from?

Comment: @Daniel the headset is "rather old" but no i don't think so

Comment: The first thing I notice is that it says it requires Windows.

Comment: @Daniel it ran perfectly fine on my old ubuntu machine

Comment: What was your old Ubuntu machine running?

Comment: @Daniel Ubuntu 14.04 just like this one

Comment: Did you install any drivers?

Comment: @Daniel no it automaticly registered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31451/discussion-between-daniel-and-marc-rasmussen).